# Unit testing an exported function in typescript

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write a unit test for an export function in typescript, which looks like this:

```
module mainStream.utilities {
    "use strict";

    export function getSpriteClassFromDataType(type: string): string {
        var retClass: string = "";

        if (type) {
            switch (type.toString()) {
                case "1":
                    retClass = "text";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    retClass = "number";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    retClass = "yesno";
                    break;
                case "4":
                    retClass = "datetime";
                    break;
                case "9":
                    retClass = "decimal";
                    break;
                case "10":
                    retClass = "xml";
                    break;

                default:
                    retClass = "text";
            }
        }

        return retClass;
    }
}
```

It is a very simple function used to grab the text value from a integer string ("1") = "text"; the code is not the most sufficient way of doing this, as an Enum could most probably have worked, I'm just trying to write a simple test for this.

This is what I have, but Karma complains about the "obj" part and because it's not in a class, I cannot use the namespace (module name) as the object either.

```
/// <reference path="../../../mainStreamApp/utilities/datatypeclassresolver.ts" />
namespace unit.tests.utilities {
    "use strict";

    describe("mainStreamApp.utilities", () => {
        describe("DataTypeClassResolver", () => {

            it("should return the sprite class name for a text data type", () => {
                spyOn(mainStreamApp.utilities, "mainStreamApp.utilities.getSpriteClassFromDataType");   
                let dataType = mainStreamApp.utilities .getSpriteClassFromDataType("1");             
                expect(mainStreamApp.utilities.getSpriteClassFromDataType).toHaveBeenCalledWith("1");
                expect(dataType).toBe("text");
            });

        });
    })
}
```

Is there a special way to do this, without having to wrap the function in a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spyOn` and method call expectation are redundant here. Just call the method and verify result:

```
it("should return the sprite class name for a text data type", () => {
    let dataType = mainStreamApp.utilities.getSpriteClassFromDataType("1");
    expect(dataType).toBe("text");
});
```